# Flutter Web: FCM cannot register Service Worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, flutter-web

I am trying to implement FCM notification inside a Flutter Web application but I am getting errors when registering my service worker. I think it might come from the way my files `index.html` and `firebase-messaging-sw.js` are made.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var devConfig = {
      apiKey: "API_KEY",
      authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
      databaseURL: "DB_URL",
      projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
      storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
      messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
      appId: "APP_ID",
      measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(devConfig);
  </script>

  <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

var devConfig = {
   apiKey: "API_KEY",
   authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
   databaseURL: "DB_URL",
   projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
   storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
   messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
   appId: "APP_ID",
   measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
};

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp(devConfig);

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

**Errors**

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at p (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js:1:10100)
    at Object.o [as messaging] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js:1:9710)
    at http://localhost:56234/firebase-messaging-sw.js:33:28
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:56234/') with script ('http://localhost:56234/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

- I am testing the application using the command `flutter run -d web-server`.
- I am correctly calling `await Firebase.initializeApp()` before starting my application in my `main.dart`.
- I am using the package `firebase_core: ^0.5.0`.
- I have tested with firebase scripts in version `7.22.1` and `7.5.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add follow ing in your index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes in the end I've added the firebase-messaging script and it was working correctly. I'll count your answer as valid.